# Prevent download from users

Tags: php, file, download

I have website, and all users can download any file in download page. Just users who have accounts in my website can download; visitor cannot see the download page until login or registering on my website. 
I want now to do some changes; I want just download any file from a download  page for active users who have more than 10 topics, any user who is less 10 topics cannot download any files. 
How can I do that?

**Downloads**

```
<?php 
if(!$allcategories)
{
    echo 'There are no downloads available!';
    return;
}

foreach($allcategories as $category)
{
?>
<p><h2><strong><?php echo $category->name?></strong></h2></p>
<ul>

<?php   
    # This loops through every download available in the category
    $alldownloads = DownloadData::GetDownloads($category->id);

    if(!$alldownloads)
    {
        echo 'There are no downloads under this category';
        $alldownloads = array();
    }

    foreach($alldownloads as $download)
    {
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo url('/downloads/dl/'.$download->id);?>">
            <?php echo $download->name?></a><br />
          <?php echo $download->description?><br />
          <em>Downloaded <?php echo $download->hits?> times</em></li>
<?php
    }
?><br />
</ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

That is my download code .

Comment: Share the user object code, how do you know if a user has 10 topics?

Comment: **Please don't embolden most of the text in your question as it makes it look like you're shouting**. THE SAME WOULD APPLY IF YOU WROTE IN CAPS. thank you.

Comment: You want something like "privileges"... You should store or count how many topics or in download or in html link check how many he/she have.

Comment: Elias Nicolas . every users show in his profile how many topic he has . and it is upadte auto ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question with no information with the framework or db you are using. 
I'll assume you are using MySQL. 
I'll also assume you have a table called `users` with id | name | email | etc
I'll also assume you have another table called topics with:
id | userid | title | desc | etc
Ok, I'll also assume that when a user logs in to your site, you are setting a session called $_SESSION["userid"];

Now on the download page, run a query at the beginning (make sure you are connected to db before the following):

```
$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from `topics` where `userid` = '$userid') or die(mysql_error());
$topicCount = mysql_result($result,0);
if($topicCount < 10){
echo "You have $topicCount topics so far. You need a minimum of 10 to get access to downloads.";
}
```

You can change that message to anything you want so the users know why they don't have access to downloads.

Good Luck

Comment: I hope it helped you.